# Magento 2 System > Export > Product where is the "Status" column?

Tags: csv, export, magento2

When I export all the products form System > Export I get a CSV with all the products but without the "Status" column.

That is weird, no? Is there any way to add this column to the CSV?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status is represented in the column with `product_online`.

If this is set to `1` it means the product is enabled. If it's set to `2` the product is disabled.

This is also how you can change the product status with Magento 2 product import: based on column `sku` and `product_online`.